# .htaccess max_execution_time

Tags: htaccess

I want to change the max_execution_time in the .htaccess file. I tried it in this way: `<IfModule mod_php5.c> php_value max_execution_time 300 </IfModule>` but then I got a *500 internal server error*. 
My .htaccess file also includes this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any idea why I got this error? Or how I can change the max_execution_time in an other way?

(I sadly do not have the possibility to change the php.ini)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can alter the index.php file and add `[set_time_limit][1](300);` anywhere below the `<?php` tag.

You can also try to set it by `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);`

*For the reason why it returns a 500 Internal Server Error, the server does not support the `php_value` and `php_flag` parameters through the htaccess file or it doesnt use the php5 module. You can try setting the `php_value` directly and check again for errors, or contact your hosting provider for support*

Comment: Thanks! `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` works fine